# How to make an external reference in a JavaScript variable value?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, serverless, cloudflare-workers

I'm setting up a serverless Google Drive indexer on Cloudflare Workers and this is how the variable declaration part of my code looks like:

```
var authConfig = {
  siteName: "My Site",
  version: "1.0",
  theme: "nox",
  client_id: "wyuwtryeuyriuwerwtytreyy",
  client_secret: "isfuyeiuwyuiryiuweyuiryiuey",
  refresh_token: "ifiweyruwyryewyruetrtyetrtw",
  roots: [
    {
      id: "123456",
      name: "Root 1",
      user: "user1",
      pass: "pass1"
    },
    {
      id: "654321",
      name: "Root 2",
      user: "user2",
      pass: "pass2"
    },
    {
      id: "2635264",
      name: "Root 3",
      user: "user3",
      pass: "pass3"
    }
  ],
  someOtherVar: "value",
  anotherRandomVar: "value"
};
```

What i'm trying to achieve is, using a plain text file hosted elsewhere (suppose https://example.com/value.txt) to get the values of `roots` in this code. So that whenever i edit the external text file (like adding or removing a root, the worker fetches those changes automatically.

How should i modify the code to do that?

Comment: Is that your actual `client_secret`?

Comment: @Dai why would i reveal my actual `client_secret` to public?

Comment: Because this site gets a lot of people copying and pasting without looking at what they’re doing.

Comment: @Dai well, though i'm a noob at coding, i'm not dumb enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options; like don’t hard coding the values, but always retrieve the file.

But most problematic is that you want to expose confidential information through a public endpoint.

You could consider storing the values as a secret:
https://blog.cloudflare.com/workers-secrets-environment/